# error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat in installing PIL in windows7

Tags: python, django, windows-7

Im using Windows 7 for developing Django 1.3.7. now I am trying to install PIL on my djangp using pip but I got an error.

```
C:\Django-Proj\myproj\myproj>pip install PIL==1.1.7
Downloading/unpacking PIL==1.1.7
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL==1.1.7
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external PIL to allow).

Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PIL==1.1.7
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Samuel\pip\pip.log
```

Now I am trying this approach by downloading http://effbot.org/media/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz but I got also an error

```
C:\pyset\Imaging-1.1.7\Imaging-1.1.7>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ArgImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageFileIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageGL.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\OleFileIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
running build_ext
building '_imaging' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Does anyone have an Idea about this? tnx in advance

Answer (score 2):

On windows you need a precompiled version of PIL unless you have the VisualC toolkit installed - try [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow) for an unofficial build.